# Batch- how to parse .txt file and find words in it

Tags: windows, parsing, loops, batch-file, text

I need to go through a `a.txt` file line by line and extract and copy the words `zzz` and `yyy` from it, store them in another `b.txt` file than loop through these words and create a command lines that looks like this :

```
blabla XXX
```

while XXX is taken one by one from the b.txt file we created before that got "zzz" and "yyy" in it.

**example:**

file a.txt

```
jsdfjdsfnsdj

yyy

sdfdsfsd

zzz
```

b.txt file will be:

```
yyy

zzz
```

and the commands created will be:

```
blabla yyy

blabla zzz
```

Comment: You can use `find` or `findstr` for the first part. A simple `for /f` loop should handle the rest. If it's really that simple you might just use `for /f` on the first file and skip the intermediate step. It looks like the matches are very straightforward.

Comment: I'm new to batch coding, can you please give me the whole script because its not working :\ even when i changed the txt directions to the ones in my comp

Answer (score 0):

use **For /F** for read line and check line with **findstr**

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do ( call :checkline %%a )
goto :eof

:checkline 
@echo %1 |findstr /g:b.txt

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo blablabla  %1 >>c.txt
ENDLOCAL

:eof
```

Comment: I'm new to batch coding, can you please give me the whole script because its not working :\ even when i changed the txt directions to the ones in my comp

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
if exist b.txt del b.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do (
    if "%%a"=="yyy" echo blabla %%a >> b.txt
    if "%%a"=="zzz" echo blabla %%a >> b.txt
)
```

I think you can make @Eric's approach work too. `findstr` is better if you actually place your search expression in the pattern file. And I think his approach should be amended to match the entire line.

```
echo ^^yyy^$>  patterns.txt
echo ^^zzz^$>> patterns.txt
for /F "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do (call :checkline %%a)
del patterns.txt
goto :eof

:checkline 
@echo %1 | findstr /g:patterns.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo blablabla %1 >>c.txt
goto :eof
```

I think you could possibly use this line without the extra hassle of pattern file. Unfortunately `findstr` doesn't truly support alternation in regular expressions but I think this works ok.

```
@echo %1 | findstr "^yyy$ ^zzz$"
```

Comment: can this script find the pattern in a txt file with several lines or just one?
because it doesn't create a c.txt file with the results in it

Comment: You have several options and your requirements aren't completely transparent. The /g option lets you have multiple searches in a file. See `findstr /?` for more info.

Comment: i dunno why but i can't find the c.txt result folder, i tried to put source file  a.txt and the .bat file in same directory and add "cd C:\..." to that directory in the batch file but i can only see the patterns.txt file created and not the result file c.txt.   

really thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you confirm that `findstr` is actually matching results? Maybe add `echo %ERRORLEVEL%` in the line after.

Comment: i run the following code but nothing shows up in patterns.txt except:
`^yyy$
^zzz$
`
 my code is:  
  `cd C:\Users\isaacd\Documents
    echo ^^yyy^$>  patterns.txt
    echo ^^zzz^$>> patterns.txt
    for /F "delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do (call :checkline %%a)
    goto :eof

:checkline 
@echo %1 | findstr /g:patterns.txt
echo %ERRORLEVEL%>>patterns.txt
if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 echo blablabla %1 >>c.txt
goto :eof`

Comment: The patterns file is supposed to only contain the strings you want to match. So that all appears to be correct. Your previous comment referred to c.txt and you didn't answer my question.